# Ist es „auf dem Tisch“ oder „auf den Tisch?“

Tags: standard-german

Zum Beispiel:

> Die Flasche ist auf **dem** Tisch.

Aber was passiert wenn man in Bewegung ist? Zum Beispiel:

> Ich lege die Flasche auf **den** Tisch.

Gibt es einer Unterschied nur weil die Flasche in Bewegung ist? Oder weil es eine Beziehung zwischen dem Subjekt und Flasche gibt? (Und dann gibt es eine zweite Beziehung zwischen der Flasche und dem Tisch?)

Answer (score 5):

### Ort (wo?) → Dativ

> Die Flasche steht *wo?*
>   Die Flasche steht *auf **dem** Tisch.*
>
> Ich sitze *wo?*
>   Ich sitze *auf **dem** Sofa.*
>
> Ich liege *wo?*
>   Ich liege *in **der** Hängematte.*

---

### Richtung (wohin?) → Akkusativ

> Ich stelle die Flasche *wohin?*
>   Ich stelle die Flasche *auf **den** Tisch.*
>
> Ich setze mich *wohin?*
>   Ich setze mich *auf **das** Sofa.*
>
> Ich lege mich *wohin?*
>   Ich lege mich *in **die** Hängematte.*

Answer (score 1):

Der Unterschied ist die Frage nach dem Ort.

Im ersten Fall ist die Frage *wo?*. Die Flasche liegt wo? Auf dem Tisch. Diese Frage wird immer mit einem Dativobjekt beantwortet.

Wo?

> In der Mülltonne
>   Im Wohnzimmer
>   Auf der Wiese
>   Im Graben
>   ...

Im zweiten Fall ist die Frage aber *wohin*! Wohin legst Du die Flasche? Auf den Tisch. Hier ist der Akkusativ nötig.

Wohin?

> In die Mülltonne
>   In das Wohnzimmer
>   Auf die Wiese
>   In den Graben
>   ...

Comment: Tausend Dank, meiner Freund!

Comment: Nach deinem Dativobjekt fragt man aber mit »wem?« und das erfragte Satzglied enthält dann keine Präposition: »Wem gehört das Haus? - Das Haus gehört **dem Onkel.**« Wenn man hingegen mit »wo?« fragt, fragt man nach einer adverbialen Bestimmung des Ortes, und die Antwort ist entweder ein Adverb »Wo bist du? - Ich bin **hier.**« oder eine Ergänzung, die mit einer Präposition beginnt »Wo bist du? - Ich bin **in der Stadt.**« Die Antwort auf »wo?« kann nie nur »der Stadt« sein.

Comment: Wenn du nach *der Stadt* mit »wem?« fragst, ist die ein Dativobjekt: »Wem kehrt Kurt den Rücken? - Kurt kehrt **der Stadt** den Rücken.«

Comment: Es ist kein Dativobjekt, sondern ein Präpositionalobjekt im Dativ.